# Multi domain login with adfs - nodeJs - passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, cross-domain, adfs

what I'm trying to achieve right now is to login in an adfs page with any "microsoft" email.

The context is an app that can be used from different clients, tipically they all got some emails built like this: "name.surname@*companyname*.it/com"
all based on Microsoft's accounts (talking about Office 365 etc.).

I'm currently using the library "passport-wsfed-saml2" on a nodeJs API router, the implementation follows the example configuration from the library ([example configuration](https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2/tree/master#configure-strategy))

Atm in the webapp the only login option is to be profiled with an internal email and then you'll be able to login (so basically everyone has the same "*@companyname.it*").

I expected everything to be set up on the adfs side, having to change nothing on my api-side, but when I tested the login with a different domain email it didn't work.

I've no access right now to logs on the adfs side (I'll have them, sooner or later), what can I check to be sure on the passport side everything is set up correctly?
Or even, is it something doable with the passport library I've mentioned?

Thanks in advance to everyone.